# Method in an enum is asking for argument when none required in declaration

Tags: swift, swift-playground

This maybe a terrible n00b question but I'm finally getting to look at Swift properly.
Imagine I have a simple enum representing a playing card.
In it I have a method that returns an `Array` of `Card`s.
The method has no arguments, but when I call it the auto-completion and compiler both state it needs one.

Notes:

- Rank and Suit are previously defined structs.
- Yes, I know 'nested for-loops considered harmful'. I'll move it to map/reduce later...
- This is running in playground file.

Code:

```
struct Card {
  var rank: Rank
  var suit: Suit

  init(rank: Rank, suit: Suit) {
    self.rank = rank
    self.suit = suit
  }

  //internal version
  func deckOfCards() -> [Card] {
    var deck = [Card]()
    for suit in Suit.allSuits {
      for rank in Rank.allRanks {
        deck.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
      }
    }
    return deck
  }
}

//external version
func deckOfCards() -> [Card] {
  var deck = [Card]()
  for suit in Suit.allSuits {
    for rank in Rank.allRanks {
      deck.append(Card(rank: rank, suit: suit))
    }
  }
  return deck
}

let externalDeck = deckOfCards()
let internalDeck = Card.deckOfCards() //this has the compiler error: Missing argument for parameter #1
```

Comment: See the notes ;) Rank is a previously defined Struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Card.deckOfCards()` is not accessed through an instance of the struct, this means that it should be a struct level function. Struct level functions are defined with the `static` keyword.

```
struct Card {
    static func deckOfCards() -> [Card] {
        var deck = [Card]()

        return deck
    }
}

let internalDeck = Card.deckOfCards()
```

Without the static keyword, the function can only be accessed through an instance of the struct.

```
struct Card {

    func anotherDeck() -> [Card] {
        var deck = [Card]()

        return deck
    }
}

let externalDeck = Card()
externalDeck.anotherDeck()
```

Comment: Yes! How did I not see that... Many thanks. Will accept as answer as soon as SO lets me.